# java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty - have tried all potential solutions I've found

Tags: java, ssl, intellij-idea, ssl-certificate

I'm aware that this error has quite a history and a number of causes, some simple and some less than simple.  I'm trying to connect to an SSL socket in a program running manually in IntelliJ on Windows.

- I've imported all three (machine, intermediate, root) certs into the Java cacerts store
- I've tried importing them in order root --> intermediate --> machine
- I've tried just the root cert using `-trustcacerts`
- I've verified that I'm using the cacerts file of the JDK that IntelliJ is using, though `-Djavax.net.debug=all` in the CLI args in Intellij doesn't log anything to the console.
- I've added `-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-20\lib\security\cacerts"`, pointing explicitly absolute path to the keystore with no luck.

  ```
    C:\WINDOWS\system32>keytool -list -keystore "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-20\lib\security\cacerts" -storepass changeit | findstr dev

    devissuingcert, Aug 15, 2023, trustedCertEntry,
    devrcmcert, Aug 15, 2023, trustedCertEntry,
    devrootcert, Aug 15, 2023, trustedCertEntry,
  ```

Thoughts?

Comment: 'I've added `-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-20\lib\security\cacerts"`': this is completely pointless, as that's the default. Duplicate.

Comment: What would make you think that the solution is in the referenced question? I of course found that question before posting, and none of the answers seems to be the case.  An identical error message doesn't indicate identical root cause.  Yes, I'm aware that cacerts is the default but explicitly set it so that I could be sure of where it is pointing.  I would think people would appreciate that, but hey.